# Why do grpc server examples use net.Listen instead of tls.Listen

Tags: ssl, go, grpc

I'm setting up a golang grpc server that will use TLS for client authorization/authentication. All the examples of server setup that I've seen use `net.Listen()` instead of `tls.Listen()`. Why is this?

```
import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/credentials"
    "net"
)

func startGRPCListener(hostport string, tlsconfig *tls.Config) (grpcServer *grpc.Server) {
    listener, _ = net.Listen("tcp", hostport)
    cred := grpc.Creds(credentials.NewTLS(tlsconfig))
    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer(cred)
    go func() {
        serveErr := grpcServer.Serve(listener)
        log.WithError(serveErr).Info("GRPC server exited")
    }() 

    return
}
```

I've noticed in a couple of working examples if I swap to tls.Listen, the connection can no longer be made. However, in other cases, this doesn't cause a problem!

I guess my question is "should I use net.Listen or tls.Listen, or does it not make a difference?"

Comment: The question of why an example does one thing or another is specific to that example and only truly answerable by the example's author, and generally totally irrelevant anyway. Perhaps if you post a question about your TLS issue, that's something the SO community could actually help with.

Answer (score 3):

> Why is this?

Because these are examples about grpc and not about TLS?
Examples tend to be examples: Simplifications to demonstrate something. Examples are not copy-paste samples for production code.

Comment: Exactly this. A TLS version would not be an example someone could copy-paste-execute to learn how it works - they'd have to set up certificates to get it working and it would add nothing to the example in terms of the gRPC functionality they're actually trying to demonstrate.